# C# Combobox SelectedIndexChanged is not updating the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 2 combo boxes with a list of team names (they are labeled as comboBox2 & comboBox3). I am using the SelectedIndexChanged Event so that when a team is selected, 2 datagrid views will display the searched criteria based off the team name. Below is the code for both comboboxes:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs2.DataSource = dataGridView2.DataSource;

            string filter = "";
            string filter2 = "";

            // Check if text fields are not null before adding to filter. 
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
            {
                if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Position"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
            {
                if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%' ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
            {
                if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ";
            }

            bs2.Filter = filter2;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs2;
            Injuries();


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                filter2 += dataGridView2.Columns["Name"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
            {
                if (filter2.Length > 0) filter2 += "AND ";
                filter2 += dataGridView2.Columns["Position"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
            {
                if (filter2.Length > 0) filter2 += "AND ";
                filter2 += dataGridView2.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%' ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
            {
                if (filter2.Length > 0) filter2 += "AND ";
                filter2 += dataGridView2.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ";
            }

            bs2.Filter = filter2;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bs2;
            Injuries();

        }
```

--

```
 private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs2.DataSource = dataGridView2.DataSource;

        string filter = "";
        string filter2 = "";

        // Check if text fields are not null before adding to filter. 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' ";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
        {
            if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
            filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Position"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
        {
            if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
            filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
        {
            if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
            filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%'";
        }

        bs2.Filter = filter2;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs2;
        Injuries();


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            filter2 += dataGridView2.Columns["Name"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' ";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
        {
            if (filter2.Length > 0) filter2 += "AND ";
            filter2 += dataGridView2.Columns["Position"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
        {
            if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
            filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
        {
            if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
            filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%'";
        }
    }
```

The issues that I am having is that

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
            {
                if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%' ";
            }
```

Works fine but

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
                {
                    if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                    filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ";
                }
```

Will not update the datagridview at all. If you need any further explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't second button update the second datagridview?

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
                {
                    if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                    filter += dataGridView2.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ";
                }
```

Seems to me you are updating twice the same DGV...?

Comment: Thank you, I missed that, my issue somewhat still remains however, Now I can search for both criteria however when I choose the second drop down the dgv is blank. 

I am using the following:

 if (filter.Length > 0) filter += "AND ";
                filter += dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%'" + " OR " + dataGridView1.Columns["Team"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%'";

Comment: Did you debug your filter condition compiled? What does it show? I.e. filter = " Team LIKE '%St. Louis%' AND Position LIKE '%Back%' "...?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the DropDownStyle property is set to the same as what it is on comboBox2